# Clear color without light

Tags: light, babylonjs

I need draw solid poligons with borders without lighting. For example, cube. All edges must be colored in same clear color (for example yellow with black border). But without lightning all scene is grayscale and with any lights edges are different (it is logical :) ). Can anybody help me with this sample scene setup, please?

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to set a material to your meshes and only use emissive Color.
Something like

```
var mat = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial()
mat.emissiveColor = BABYLON.Color3.Red()
mesh.material = mat
```

For edges you may want to have a look to edgesRenderer or outlineRenderer